# Double Click on Kendo Grid row's for React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I'm using the React Grid component and I'm looking for a way to fire a function when double click a row.

I found a `rowClick` function and I can use it now to select a row or handle an onClick event : `<Grid rowClick={e => yourFunction(e)}>` .
But there is no function to handle a doubleClick event.

This is my approach, I passed a `onDoubleClick()` function as props to my component, and bind it with the listener of `doubleClick` on `componentDidMount` for each row :

```
componentDidMount() {
    let { onDoubleClick } = this.props;
      if (onDoubleClick) {
        const rows = document
          .getElementsByClassName('k-widget k-grid')[0]
          .getElementsByClassName('k-grid-table')[0]
          .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
          .getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          rows[i].addEventListener('dblclick', () => onDoubleClick());
        }
      }
  }
```

For the moment this works but I'm not able to pass the clicked row data to my function.
Is there any hack to retrieve the row's data using the element ?
Like this for example : onDoubleClick(kendo.data.DataSource(rows[i])) => return the json data to function.

Comment: In the jquery version, you can do var item = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); where "grid" is a reference to the grid widget.  I don't know if the react api is the same though.

Answer (score 2):

The grid have a [rowRender](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/GridProps/#toc-rowrender) property, that can be used as a [RenderProp](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) for fully modifying the rows, including attaching them a rowClick using the native React approach.

```
rowRender(trElement, dataItem) {
    const trProps = {
        ...trElement.props,
        onDoubleClick: () => {
            //place your logic here
        }            
    };
    return React.cloneElement(trElement, { ...trProps }, trElement.props.children);
}
```

You may find this live example for how to attach mouse mousedown, blur and focus for the GridRow in the [InCell editing demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-in-cell/) The same logic for the onDoubleClick can be used as in my code-snipped above.